# No cover for music files in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 22.04, music, ogg-vorbis

I am using latest version of Ubuntu LTS 22.04.1 and it is up to date system. I have ogg music files with covers and they don't show up in  file manager (I presume its nautilus since its main Ubuntu release and not a spin-off). When I install Ubuntu, I thought maybe after some updates, this problem will be fixed but it did not get fixed. I have 7th generation CPU and RX 560 GPU with 16GB RAM. So it is pretty solid computer. ogg music file covers use to show in my previous Linux distribution i.e. KDE neon but it does not show up in here. Is there any fix?

Comment: Preferences/Performance/Show thumbnails. Make sure you haven't zoomed too far out.

Comment: I already have. Doesn't work.